# Connect Laravel to MongoDB database

Tags: laravel, mongodb

How can I connect Laravel with a MongoDB database? Unfortunately, I'm unable to connect MongoDB with Laravel using the latest Laravel version.

It gives the following error.

> InvalidArgumentException: Database connection [Users] not configured.

Comment: How are you trying to connect? Laravel doesn't have native MongoDB support but there's [a package](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) that adds it.